# jQuery selecting option not working for select not yet added to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select a specific option within a select element that has not yet been added to the DOM, but it does not seem to be working. Is what I'm trying to do not possible?

I would like to click the "Add Select" button, and see a new select element added to the DOM with the "0" option selected.

Here's a

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/Lm7d714q/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <select class="mySelect">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<button id="addSelect">Add Select</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $template = $('.mySelect').first().clone(),
        $container = $('#container');

    $template.find('option').each(function(i, option) {
       $(option).prop('selected', false); 
    });

    $('#addSelect').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $container.append($template.clone());
    });
});
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the new select is added but it has the "2" option selected.

I also tried resetting the select with `$template.val('0')`, but that did not work either. The select still appears with the "2" option selected.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7d714q/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove attribute `selected` because setting property on none DOM element doesn't set its attribute, element isn't linked to DOM:

```
$template.find(':selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Will accept the answer when I'm allowed in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#addSelect').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $a = $template.clone();
        $a.find('option').prop('selected',false)
        $container.append($a);
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7d714q/4/).

Comment: I see that this is working, but why? If I'm already setting each option with `$(option).prop('selected', false);` when the `$template` is first created, why do I also need to set the value using `$templateClone.val(0);`?

Comment: @A. Wolff answer is better !

Answer (score 0):

```
$template.find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7d714q/8/